# Session is not cleared even after RemoveAll

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, session

```
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.RemoveAll();

        System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

I am doing this much code

still

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["User"]  is not null
```

:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call both `Clear` and `RemoveAll`. Here's how the `RemoveAll` is implemented:

```
public void RemoveAll()
{
    this.Clear();
}
```

Also here's a quote from [KB 899918](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899918):

> When the Web application requires a
>   logon and offers a log off page or
>   option, we recommend that you clear
>   the session state when the user has
>   logged off the Web site. To clear the
>   session state, call the
>   Session.Abandon method. The
>   Session.Abandon method lets you flush
>   the session state without waiting for
>   the session state time-out. By
>   default, this time-out is a 20-minute
>   sliding expiration. This expiration is
>   refreshed every time that the user
>   makes a request to the Web site and
>   presents the session ID cookie. The
>   Abandon method sets a flag in the
>   session state object that indicates
>   that the session state should be
>   abandoned. The flag is examined and
>   then acted upon at the end of the page
>   request. **Therefore, the user can use
>   session objects within the page after
>   you call the Abandon method.** As soon
>   as the page processing is completed,
>   the session is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `session.flush();` which worked for me.
Not sure if it can help you.

Comment: session.flush()? which language r u using?

Comment: It is c#.net...I used this with java